# What is the "Energy" equivalent of the Magnitude Spectrum

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, magnitude, signal-energy

I have a semantic issue regarding the discrete spectrum $X[k]$ of a time domain signal with limited length $x[n]$, so we're talking about the FFT. Now, when I what to compare the bandwidth and amplitude of sinusoidal (a peak) in $|X_1[k]|$ vs. another $|X_2[k]|$, am I allowed to talk about the sinusoidal having more or less energy or having the energy spread over a wider frequency range?

As far as I understand, the energy spectrum is defined as $|X[k]|^2$ and when I would directly use values, I would need to take these in order to talk about energy. Though In practice I'm working with the decibel magnitude spectrum $20 \log_{10}|X[k]|$ anyway. My argument would be that even though the graph I'm describing doesn't directly display the energy, it displays a value directly proportional to energy, especially in the  decibel case were as far as I know the difference is simply a factor of $2$, as in

$$
20 \log_{10}|X[k]| = 10 \log_{10}|X[k]|^2
$$

If this wouldn't be technically correct, is there an equivalent to "energy" in the magnitude spectrum? I've never heard someone explain that the magnitude of a sinusoidal is spread over a larger frequency band.

Comment: I don't understand – a sinusoid has energy at exactly one frequency (that's kinda its definition). Its energy is never *spread* out over a frequency *range*, though you might say that you *observe* its energy in multiple discrete frequency *bins* (due to leakage). So, are you referring to leakage there?

Comment: @MarcusMüller In the instance, the sinusoidal might change in frequency over time within the analysed audio frame or not. When it changes, we get a wider lobe with lower magnitude. So yes, I'm talking about leakage technically. In which case maybe it's more precise to state that the energy is spread over multiple energy bins?

Comment: but if it changes frequency, it's not a sinusoid. (and that's not the leakage I was referring to.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Isn't a sinusoidal simply a sine wave with $x[n] = \sin(2 \pi f t)$ in which case $f$ might change?

Comment: if that $f$ changes, it's not a pure sinusoid anymore! It has a bandwidth. It's now a modulated signal.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Really not sure if I agree here. This would also mean that a sinusoidal is only a sinusoidal if we observe an infinite length. But surely makes sense (or doesn't harm) to be more precise about it. So, frequency-modulated sinusoidal it is. :D 
In which case how would you describe the effect, that a more modulated frequency spreads more "energy" over a wider frequency range?

Comment: yeah, so we call that "spread" *bandwidth of the signal*.

Comment: (also your math is right, the dB(amplitude) and dB(power) are the same - that's why they're defined like that)

Comment: (and "infinite" is implied in you using the FFT == DFT to analyze the spectrum: that assumes periodic repitition of your signal; otherwise, you wouldn't get a discrete spectrum!)